# Is Cmd Prompt the same as Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: windows, terminal, command-prompt

I'm sorry if this is a simple question:

I want to swap from ubuntu to windows for my web dev (personal preference). I'm used to using the terminal in ubuntu and the commands there and I was wondering whether the command prompt in windows is the same? Do the commands do the same?

If not, is there a way to get a terminal for windows the same as ubuntu?

Comment: Off-topic, no and [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Hah, funny, people tend to want the Linux shell terminal over the Windows CMD :-P

Comment: They are not even close. Sure some of the same commands exist but from a shell perspective command prompt is nothing like Linux shell

Comment: @CodeCaster, you beat me to it!

Comment: Sorry @codecaster but I don't understand how it's off topic? I asked if they're the same and if not, how do I use a similar thing?

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, it's about programming. Questions about consoles of different OSes goes on different sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No the Command prompt is not same as the Linux shell you may find some commands resembling to those of the shell in Linux (terminal) however to get a more Linux shell like environment you can install cygwin or GOW (Gnu on Windows). It will give you a bash.

[You can find Cygwin here .](http://cygwin.com/) and
[You can find GOW here .](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki)

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Its not the same, as others have answered, but since the latest version of windows 10 there is a way of running linux bash terminal in Windows.

Have a look in [Bash on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about#).

It is actually running Ubuntu inside your Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Windows is based on DOS but Ubuntu is based on Linux. Each of those has its own commands, with some similar commands. I personally prefer Linux commands as they are easier to understand and more simple than DOS commands. You can't use Linux commands in DOS nor the reverse.